# Парсинг Python Requests

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, requests

Пытаюсь спарсить значения рейтинга с сайта, как я понял нужны куки.

Но response выдает ошибку.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import requests
import re

session = requests.Session()

session.get("https://www.wildberries.ru/services/besplatnaya-dostavka?desktop=1#terms-delivery",
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
    }
)

class getCookies():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.cookiejar = requests.get(url).cookies
        self.url = url

    def check_domain(self, domain):
        try:
            base_domain = re.compile("(?<=\.).+\..+$").search(domain).group()
        except AttributeError:
            base_domain = domain

        if base_domain in self.url:
            print("\"prov=" + str(dict(self.cookiejar)) + "\"")
            return str(dict(self.cookiejar))
        else:
            print("No cookies for " + domain + " in this jar!")

new_instance = getCookies("https://www.wildberries.ru")

response = session.post(
    'https://www.wildberries.ru/webapi/poo/byids',
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0',
        'Cookie': new_instance.check_domain("https://www.wildberries.ru")
    },
    data = {
        0: 11849
    }
)

print(response.json)
```

Ошибка:

> "prov={}"
> <bound method Response.json of <Response [404]>> `

Comment: Это не ошибка, вы просто печатаете ссылку на метод `json`. Метод надо вызывать со скобочками: `print(response.json())` Другое дело, что там `json`-а в ответе нет и поэтому будет ошибка. И даже просто `response.status_code` и `response.text` какую-то фигню возвращают, это надо разбираться, что там как и почему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывается:)

```
import requests

json_data = [11849]

res = requests.post('https://www.wildberries.ru/webapi/poo/byids', json=json_data)
print(res)
a = res.json()
print('рейтинг', a['value']['11849']['rate'])
```

вывод:

```
<Response [200]>
рейтинг 4.93
```

За содействия благодарим https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: Лучший брат, помог!)